# Making MVC Controllers in Umbraco, But Can't build the website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am looking for making some MVC Controller and Models so add my desired functionality to my website, but How can I add a controller while the project can't even build, because there are lots of compilation errors in umbraco internal pages (e.g. in Umbraco/ and UmbracoClient/ folders).

How would I overcome these problems and make my own controllers - models? don't they need a compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your compilation errors I can't be sure, but unless your version of Umbraco is seriously corrupt the most likely cause is because there is a problem with references - either to packages in the packages folder (which Umbraco 6.x.x builds create) or to another folder (references?) that someone may have added if you are using mvc bridge and Umbraco 4.x.x.

Assuming this is a 6.x.x build then are the errors connected with missing assemblies?  Are the permissions on the folders (like packages) in your solution allowing access?  Is the packages folder missing?

You could create a new blank Umbraco instance and migrate your work so far if your Umbraco install is corrupt.